# Query filter into List<String> with Objectify 3.1

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have the class :

```
public class GuideStore {
    ...
    private List<String> privileges;
    ...
}
```

And I make the filter with objectify like:

```
Query<GuideStore> query = ofy().query(GuideStore.class);
query.filter("privileges", "any_value");
```

I don't get any result. Is correct the query?

Comment: Not is optimal the solution but it worked, just I have to make or create again the query to get the object (List or ArrayList) privileges.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, I try with the answer, but I'll try change the structure of my datastore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to do in query, than you need to do:

```
query.filter("any_value IN", privileges);
```

But do not forget that this operation will not be very fast.